# Cart in WooCommerce store not auto updating

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I have a WooCommerce store, however when users edit the cart the total and cost do not update. When the user presses the UPDATE CART button the cart refreshes and simply goes back to the original product amount entered.

I have the CART file here.

```
    <?php
/**
 * Cart totals
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart-totals.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.3.6
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

?>
<div class="cart_totals <?php if ( WC()->customer->has_calculated_shipping() ) echo 'calculated_shipping'; ?>">

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_totals' ); ?>

    <h2><?php _e( 'Cart Totals', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

    <table cellspacing="0" class="shop_table shop_table_responsive">

        <tr class="cart-subtotal">
            <th><?php _e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <td data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_subtotal_html(); ?></td>
        </tr>

        <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_coupons() as $code => $coupon ) : ?>
            <tr class="cart-discount coupon-<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $code ) ); ?>">
                <th><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_label( $coupon ); ?></th>
                <td data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( wc_cart_totals_coupon_label( $coupon, false ) ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_html( $coupon ); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php if ( WC()->cart->needs_shipping() && WC()->cart->show_shipping() ) : ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_before_shipping' ); ?>

            <?php wc_cart_totals_shipping_html(); ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_after_shipping' ); ?>

        <?php elseif ( WC()->cart->needs_shipping() && 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_shipping_calc' ) ) : ?>

            <tr class="shipping">
                <th><?php _e( 'Shipping', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <td data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Shipping', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php woocommerce_shipping_calculator(); ?></td>
            </tr>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_fees() as $fee ) : ?>
            <tr class="fee">
                <th><?php echo esc_html( $fee->name ); ?></th>
                <td data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $fee->name ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_fee_html( $fee ); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php if ( wc_tax_enabled() && 'excl' === WC()->cart->tax_display_cart ) :
            $taxable_address = WC()->customer->get_taxable_address();
            $estimated_text  = WC()->customer->is_customer_outside_base() && ! WC()->customer->has_calculated_shipping()
                    ? sprintf( ' <small>(' . __( 'estimated for %s', 'woocommerce' ) . ')</small>', WC()->countries->estimated_for_prefix( $taxable_address[0] ) . WC()->countries->countries[ $taxable_address[0] ] )
                    : '';

            if ( 'itemized' === get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_total_display' ) ) : ?>
                <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_tax_totals() as $code => $tax ) : ?>
                    <tr class="tax-rate tax-rate-<?php echo sanitize_title( $code ); ?>">
                        <th><?php echo esc_html( $tax->label ) . $estimated_text; ?></th>
                        <td data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $tax->label ); ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $tax->formatted_amount ); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <tr class="tax-total">
                    <th><?php echo esc_html( WC()->countries->tax_or_vat() ) . $estimated_text; ?></th>
                    <td data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( WC()->countries->tax_or_vat() ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_taxes_total_html(); ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_before_order_total' ); ?>

        <tr class="order-total">
            <th><?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <td data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_order_total_html(); ?></td>
        </tr>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_after_order_total' ); ?>

    </table>

    <div class="wc-proceed-to-checkout">
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout' ); ?>
    </div>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_totals' ); ?>

</div>
```

Does anyone have any ideas what could be wrong with it?

Comment: How is the cart being edited? Are products being added? Are they deleted? Has the cart template been overridden in your theme?

Comment: You have to be more explicit… comment the code to let us know where you have made some changes… Have you any customization un function.php file?